# Youtube: start and end parameters not working with fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, video, ionic-framework, youtube

I have a div in html

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

In the JS file I have the following code

```
var player = new YT.Player("player", {
   height: '0',
   width: '0',
   playerVars: {
       'showinfo': 0,
       'rel': 0
   },
   events: {
       'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
   }
});

$scope.playVideo = function(videoURL) {
   player.loadVideoByUrl($sce.getTrustedResourceUrl(videoURL));
};

function fullScreen() {
   var e = document.getElementById("player");
   e.requestFullscreen();
}    

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
   switch (event.data) {
       case -1:
          fullScreen();
          break;
       default:
          break;
   }
};
```

The problem is that when I click on a button, I call the `playVideo()` function. It eventually calls the `fullScreen()` function and the video runs fullscreen.
The video starts from the beginning and not from the specified start time in the URL.

Example call:

```
$scope.playVideo("https://www.youtube.com/embed/Xy_7q1xMnOg?start=60");
```

I expect the video to start playing from 61st second and in fullscreen.
It is playing in fullscreen but it is starting from the beginning.

Am I missing something? Or please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: which player are you using?

Comment: Im embedding the URL with iframe. So default browser player is being used.